# why this union on two select queries doesnt work?

Tags: mysql

problem statement - https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-report/

attempted answer:

```
select students.name,grades.grade,students.marks
from students
join grades
on grades.min_mark <= students.marks and grades.max_mark>= students.marks
where grade >=8
order by grade desc, students.name asc
union
select null,grades.grade,students.marks
from students
join grades
on grades.min_mark <= students.marks and grades.max_mark>= students.marks
where grade < 8
order by grade desc, students.marks asc;
```

when i enter this query it returns an error that i have an sql syntax at 'union'.

the two select queries work on their own

```
select students.name,grades.grade,students.marks
from students
join grades
on grades.min_mark <= students.marks and grades.max_mark>= students.marks
where grade >=8
order by grade desc, students.name asc;
select null,grades.grade,students.marks
from students
join grades
on grades.min_mark <= students.marks and grades.max_mark>= students.marks
where grade < 8
order by grade desc, students.marks asc;
```

these queries work and infact this is also the answer since i guess hackerrank unions by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the order of the rows inside each of the queries is not allowed, unless the queries are parenthesized, but still this is not how the final result will be ordered.

Remove the 2 `ORDER BY` clauses and add only 1 at the end, like:

```
order by grade desc, name
```

which will apply to the resultset of the unioned queries.